# EXC BAD ACCESS after hitting default in switch statement

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, exc-bad-access

I have this simple switch statement:

```
switch ([sender tag]) {
    case 0:
        [NVAlertView showNVAlertViewFromView:self.view 
                                       title:@"STOCK NUMBER" 
                                 description:@"XXXXXXXXXXX" 
                                 cancelTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                  otherTitle:@"DONE" 
                                dismissBlock:^(BOOL canceled, NSString *description) {
                                    if (!canceled) {
                                        [newItem setObject:description forKey:@"stocknum"];
                                    }
                                }];
        NSLog(@"YOP!");
        break;

    case kDescription:
        [NVAlertView showNVAlertViewFromView:self.view 
                                       title:@"DESCRIPTION" 
                                 description:@"Enter a description here." 
                                 cancelTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                  otherTitle:@"DONE" 
                                dismissBlock:^(BOOL canceled, NSString *description) {
                                    if (!canceled) {
                                        [newItem setObject:description forKey:@"description"];
                                    }
                                }];
        break;

    case kBrandName:
        [NVAlertView showNVAlertViewFromView:self.view 
                                       title:@"BRAND NAME" 
                                 description:@"Enter a brand name here." 
                                 cancelTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                  otherTitle:@"DONE" 
                                dismissBlock:^(BOOL canceled, NSString *description) {
                                    if (!canceled) {
                                        [newItem setObject:description forKey:@"description"];
                                    }
                                }];
        break;

    case kPrice:
        [NVAlertView showNVAlertViewFromView:self.view 
                                       title:@"PRICE" 
                                 description:@"$199.99" 
                                 cancelTitle:@"Cancel" 
                                  otherTitle:@"DONE" 
                                dismissBlock:^(BOOL canceled, NSString *description) {
                                    if (!canceled) {
                                        [newItem setObject:description forKey:@"description"];
                                    }
                                }];
        break;

    default:
        NSLog(@"default");
        break;
}
```

Everytime a a value hits the default case, it prints out "default" and program crashes because of EXC BAD ACCESS. What's causing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any code that follows the switch statement?  From the description, it sounds as if the problem may follow the switch.

Comment: There's nothing after the switch statement. The function ends. Switch is the only statement there

Comment: EXEC BAD ACCESS are often premature release/dangling pointers. Nothing in the scope of the snippet should cause that - so the error is probably being introduced either before or after this method. The end of the switch may be the last code in the run cycle, which is why you see the error right after the default case - even though that is not what is causing it.

Comment: I've enabled NSZombieEnabled but nothing shows up there either..

Comment: There's something wrong with my formatting or some kind of weird typo. Only the first case works. The cases which cause a crash, I made them the first case in my switch statement and they work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the scope of newItem, that you are setting values on in the block?

It's possible that it's gone out of scope by the time your dismiss block is called - keep in mind that your alert view is presented and waiting for your input, but the code keeps executing and leaves your switch statement (and method, based on your explanation)

Instead of performing the operation directly in the block, you could setup another method that creates newItem and sets up it's values, and call that particular method from within the dismissBlock.

Answer (score 2):

EXC_BAD_ACCESS often caused by accessing objects which have already been deallocated.

Check the objects in the line after this switch block to make sure they have a retain count > 0.  I'd also check sender too.

Comment: +1 Right idea. More generally, it's caused by using an invalid pointer. You might get one of those by accessing an object that has been deallocated, or by using a pointer that was never initialized in the first place, or by reading/writing past the end of some chunk of memory.